# why does POST not see attribute set in GET

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I do not understand why the POST method in GAE does not see an attribute set in GET when GET is run before POST. the following is a simple illustration:

app.yaml

---

```
application: post-does-not-see-get
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.py
```

---

index.py

---

```
import logging
import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  formstring = '''<form method="post" action="/">
<p>Enter sth: <input type="text" name="sth"/></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p></form>'''

  def get(self):
    self.a=5
    logging.info('a: '+str(self.a))
    self.response.out.write(self.formstring)

  def post(self):
    self.response.out.write('<p>'+self.a+'</p>\n')
    self.response.out.write(self.formstring)

def main():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
      [('/.*', MainHandler)],      debug=True)
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

---

while the following shows that post sees the change made in get

```
class B:
    a=3
    def get(self):
        self.a=4
    def post(self):
        print('a from post: '+str(self.a))

q=B()
q.post()
q.get()
q.post()
```

Comment: The 'webapp' framework you're using here has been end-of-lifed. The successor, webapp2, has a section documenting how handlers work here - you might find it helpful: https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/handlers.html#handlers-101

Answer (score 3):

Don't try and store state in classes across requests. GAE, like most web environments, runs multiple processes - potentially in multiple separate containers or even datacentres - to serve your requests. There is absolutely no guarantee that subsequent requests will be served by the same process.

Store persistent data in the datastore, or memcache. Webapp has a [sessions framework](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html) which can help with this.

Comment: I am using both datastore and sessions in my real code, but was puzzled why GAE breaks the OOP paradigm and methods do not see the class attribute.

Comment: It doesn't "break the oop paradigm". Why do you think it does? Variables set on an instance within the same request will of course be visible as with any other Python code.

Comment: when I run on localhost then I am using the same process, so google has deliberately changed something to make one method not see what another method did. anyway, I understand your answer and the implication to use sessions for passing non-permanent stuff.

Comment: A new instance of the RequestHandler class you attach to the route is instantiated for each request, so saying "there is no guarantee subsequent requests will be served by the process" is true, but not relevant.